# Split string to list

Tags: java, list, split

I am trying to split a string to List where the delimiter is the `$_$`.

For example the text 
Lorem ipsum dolor $*$ sit amet, consectetur adipiscing $*$ elit. Aliquam $_$ eu. 
I would like to convert to o list with elements

```
el1= Lorem ipsum dolor
el2= sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
el3- elit. Aliquam 
el4= eu.
```

I tried the code bellow with no success.Is there any other way?

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("$_$")));
```

Comment: dollar is a reserved regex value so you will need to escape it with backslashes

Comment: i see you want two delimiters? if so can try split("\\$_\\$|\\$\\$")

Answer (score 3):

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\$_\\$")));
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(s.split("\\$_\\$")); // or simply this
```

As `$` has a special meaning (end-of-text) you need to regex-escape it by a backslash. In a String literal a backslash has to be escaped itself - with a backslash.